# In a mixed javascript 2D array, how can I choose the element which has biggest number?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in Javascript that looks like `[ [.13, "A"], [.59, "C"], [.43, "B"] ]` How can I get the letter of the element which has the largest number value? I suspect array map or reduce might do it but I'm confused.

Comment: Either loop and keep track of the largest one, and use it at the end, or sort the array and then get the first/last one (depending on how you sort).

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` as follows:

```js
const arr = [ [.13, "A"], [.59, "C"], [.43, "B"] ];
let max = arr.reduce((acc, item) => (acc[0] > item[0]) ? acc : item);
console.log(max[1]);
```

Comment: Hi @majed-badawi how do I choose, say, the first element in arr if the numbers were all .13?

Answer (score 1):

Same approach as the previous answer, but using the destructuring assignment and a variable with the target index which is a little fancier.

```js
const index = 0,
      arr = [ [.13, "A"], [.59, "C"], [.43, "B"] ],
      [_, max] = arr.reduce((r, c) => r[index] < c[index] ? c : r);

console.log(max);
```